# Parsing argument 1 of CreateFileA from incompatible pointer type (Trying to create a hash from file content)

Tags: c

Im trying to understand an example free available to create an md5 hash from file content.

But Im getting an warning "passing argument 1 of CreateFileA from incompatible pointer type. Do you know what can be the issue?

Maybe is the location where the filename.txt is, I have it in the desktop. Do you know if that can be the problem? And if yes, how to check the current directory that the code os looking for to check if this is the issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define MD5LEN  16

DWORD main()
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    LPCWSTR filename=L"filename.txt";
    // Logic to check usage goes here.

    hFile = CreateFile(filename,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("Error opening file %s\nError: %d\n", filename,
            dwStatus);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    // Get handle to the crypto provider
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        PROV_RSA_FULL,
        CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    while (bResult = ReadFile(hFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE,
        &cbRead, NULL))
    {
        if (0 == cbRead)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (!CryptHashData(hHash, rgbFile, cbRead, 0))
        {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
            CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return dwStatus;
        }
    }

    if (!bResult)
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("ReadFile failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    cbHash = MD5LEN;
    if (CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, rgbHash, &cbHash, 0))
    {
        DWORD i;
        printf("MD5 hash of file %s is: ", filename);
        for (i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c", rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
    }

    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return dwStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateFile` is a macro that aliases to either `CreateFileA` (single-byte) or `CreateFileW` (multi-byte) versions.  You are obviously compiling with single-byte character type, but you are giving it a wide string as the filename.

One way to fix it is:

```
LPCSTR filename = "filename.txt";
```

Or use the wide-character version `CreateFileW`.  This might be preferable because of the unfortunate way Windows file systems deal with unicode filenames.

Or you can even engage Microsoft with the whole disastrous "T" character design:

```
LPCTSTR filename = _T( "filename.txt" );
```

Yuck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now Im not getting any error but Im getting the message "Error opening file fiename.txt Error:2  Process returned 2 (0x2)". Do you know how to check the current path where the code is looking for the file?